# Requirement.txt file for Render while using conda environment

Tags: python, render, requirements.txt, virtual-environment

I am new with this stuff but I am trying to set up flask app using Render's web service and I have problem with requirements.txt file and deploying keeps failing.

I have created virtual environment with conda and made requirement file using "conda list -e > requirements.txt" command but can't seem to make it work. As build command in server side I tried default option: $ pip install -r requirements.txt which didnt work and $ conda install --file requirements.txt but it didn't recognize conda command. What should I do?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. _Specifically_, what does "I have problem with requirements.txt file" mean?

Answer (score 1):

conda export and pip export don't have the same format. If you want to export dependencies in pip format use:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

And then just use `pip install -r requirements.txt`

If you want to make a new env that will use requirements.txt file exported by conda, use:

```
conda list -e > requirements.txt
```

and then:

```
conda create --name <your-new-env> --file <requirements file>
```

But if you need to install dependencies in an existing env, use the:

```
conda install --file <requirements file>
```

As to why it didn't recognize `conda` command, please update your question with more info, and I will edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: When given build command: conda install --file <equirements.txt, Render's web service gives error: bash: conda: command not found when trying to deploy it.


When I tried pip freeze > requirements.txt and build command in web service: pip install -r requirements.txt it gave error  ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/C:/ci_311/certifi_1676421629969/work/certifi'

Comment: Apparently command: pip list --format=freeze > requirements.txt worked! I still don't know why I can't use conda in Render's web service

Comment: yeah regarding that certify weird thing, just delete the whole line, shouldn't produce an error after that. unfortunately, im not familiar with Render's web service

Comment: Sorry, I didn't quite understand, delete what line?

Comment: that certifi_... thing